# Set server IP for multi-user windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, multi-user

I've wrote a `WinForms` app for multi-users purpose with `DataContext` data Provider. We know we should set the App.config file (including connection string) like below before making the setup file for the customer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.MyDBonnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source= 192.168.17.1;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Since the server IP might change, my idea is to make the organization’s IT department give me a URL containing a file in which the server (that MyDB attached there) IP is stored. So, I code as below to read from that file:

```
class GetServerIP
{
    private string getServerIP ()
    {
        string ConnString = "";
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://www.OrgITDept/Files/MyAppServerIP.xml");
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == " connectionString "))
            {
                if (xmlReader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    ConnString = "Data Source=" + xmlReader.GetAttribute("IPAdress") + "Initial Catalog = MyDB; Integrated Security = True";
                }
            }
        }
        return ConnString;
    }
}
```

Then I think I can invoke the above method to substitute the line “connectionString” in App.config file with it’s output and set the connection string in runtime (ex in LogIn form). Something like this:

```
public void WritingXml()
{
    string dynamicConnStr = getServerIP();
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"App.config");
    XmlNodeList userNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//configuration/connectionStrings/connectionString");

    foreach (XmlNode u in userNodes)
    {
        u.Attributes["connectionString"].Value = dynamicConnStr;
    }

    xmlDoc.Save(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"App.config");
}
```

I have some questions:

1. IS my idea viable?
2. Is it possible to edit the App.config file after the app setup file being created? (Because in solution folder/bin there is no App.config file. Indeed it’s located in the solution root folder and as far as I know, we create setup file (by ex InstallAwere software) from bin folder not the whole solution folder)
3. Are there any security issues to be coped with?
4. If we put a password to the file containing server IP (for a higher security level) is it possible to read it’s content by code like above?

Any suggestions or alternative ideas or security considerations will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're solving a problem by creating another, how do you know that URL won't change? And most important, how will that web site know the actual config to deliver? In any case, doing that when building the project is doomed to failure, a better place to do is when running the setup, it'll query the server and create and deploy App.config at that point, not hardocded within the setup.

Comment: Or as a better alternative, why not provide the user some easy-to-use screen to choose the server? And saving the result to a suitably settings file.

Comment: `app.config` is in the bin folder - it gets copied/renamed during build to be `<exename>.config`.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, you'r wright, there are two of them there, one is <appname>.exe.config and the other is <appname>.vshost.exe.config. Which of them is used when the app is going to run?

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, would you please explain more about your solution? To make it clearer, there are more than a thousand users that know nothing about server, IP and ... They just run the app to use it. That URL is a kind of contract between me and the IT department and they are responsible to save the correct server IP address there. By the way, I'm really curious about knowing more of your idea if you mind.

Comment: Is it possible that the app queries the active servers just after being started and search for MYDB, and find the server IP? If so, your idea is brilliant. It'll be very kind of you if guiding me through that specially by some pieces of code. Thanks in advance.